# The referenced dll could not available in the page

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I have created a class file with a name space of name1. I have created the dll for that. I referenced this dll in my webapplication. But in the namespace section i can't get this namespace 'name1' in the intellisence. I am using the .net 3.5 frame work

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the class public?  Only public classes are visible to other projects.  And if a namespace has no public classes, Intellisense won't display the namespace, either.